# Run X11 Server on top of Windows Terminal Server

Tags: ssh, putty, x11-forwarding, terminal-server, exceed

I would like to connect to a unix machine (GUI) over Windows Terminal Server(WTS) with multiple users (desktops). An X11 server is installed on the WTS (OpenText Exceed). I start it. I start a putty on WTS (with X11 forwarding) it is just getting a display number of one user on WTS. (if it is mine - it is ok).

My window might be visible on the desktop of another user. Or the window of another user appears on my desktop.

How to configure this properly? I would like to avoid using a fix display number in putty.

---

putty settings:
Connection -> SSH -> X11

- Enable X11 = yes
- X display location = empty (I can workaround here by setting the current display number of the actual user, for example: localhost:24.0)
- Mit-Magic-Cookie
- X authority file = empty

---

Update: the security aspect is solved: exceed -> security -> disable host-access. This will make it impossible to get the window of the other user. (The host-access was used for a very old application).
With XStart  everything is perfect (without putty).
Not solved: putty has no idea about the display number. It only takes one. Sometimes it is a random match to the own (then works). Usually it is a display of someone else and the connection is rejected by the XServer of the other user.

Comment: We need more information about your configuration, and your putty parameters. Your question title also doesn't make sense, as you can't run X11 in Windows.

Comment: I inserted my putty settings. X11 is a client-server windowing system. I started the X-Server on Windows (WTS) and connected to a unix machine over SSH. I use OpenText Exceed as X-server (also tried VcXsrv). If I am the only user on windows, there is no problem. But my goal was to have several desktops/users in the same time.